# Bootstrap Contact Form not posting

Tags: javascript, php, html, twitter-bootstrap, express

I'm following this tutorial to create a form:

https://bootstrapious.com/p/how-to-build-a-working-bootstrap-contact-form

At the bottom of the contact form HTML, I added the scripts:

```
  <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js'>   </script>
  <script src='js/validator.js'></script>
  <script src='js/contact.js'></script>
```

The validator file is from Bootstrap, which I downloaded. I know it works because it validates my form as I fill it out.

When I submit the form, nothing happens. I get the following error in console:

```
  POST http://www.example.com/php/contact.php 404 (Not Found)
```

I put the php file in a php folder so that part has changed but everything else is the same. I've tried it by placing the php file in the same folder as the contact page and get a similar message:

```
  POST http://www.example.com/contact.php 404 (Not Found)
```

I'm wondering if it is because I am using node and express. I am I suppose to do something in the following index.js file?

This is my index.js:

```
  const express = require('express');
  const  app = express();
  const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

  app.use(express.static('public'));
  app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

  app.get('/', function (request, response) {
      response.render('index');
  });

  app.get('/projects', function (request, response) {
      response.render('projects');
  });

  app.get('/about', function (request, response) {
      response.render('about');
  });

  app.get('/contact', function (request, response) {
      response.render('contact');
  });

  app.listen(port, function () {
       console.log('Listening on port ' + port);
 });
```

Here is the form on the Contact page - HTML:

```
<form id="contact-form" method="post" action="php/contact.php" role="form">
  <div class="messages"></div>
  <div class="controls">
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="form_name">Firstname *</label>
                  <input id="form_name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your firstname *" required="required" data-error="Firstname is required.">
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="form_lastname">Lastname *</label>
                  <input id="form_lastname" type="text" name="surname" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your lastname *" required="required" data-error="Lastname is required.">
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="form_email">Email *</label>
                  <input id="form_email" type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your email *" required="required" data-error="Valid email is required.">
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="form_phone">Phone</label>
                  <input id="form_phone" type="tel" name="phone" class="form-control" placeholder="Please enter your phone">
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="form_message">Message *</label>
                  <textarea id="form_message" name="message" class="form-control" placeholder="Message for me *" rows="4" required="required" data-error="Please,leave us a message."></textarea>
                  <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-send" value="Send message">
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
              <p class="text-muted"><strong>*</strong> These fields are required. Contact form template by <a href="http://bootstrapious.com" target="_blank">Bootstrapious</a>.</p>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

contact.php:

```
<?php
    $from = 'Demo contact form <demo@domain.com>';

    $sendTo = 'Demo contact form <demo@domain.com>';

    $subject = 'New message from contact form';

    $fields = array('name' => 'Name', 'surname' => 'Surname', 'phone' => 'Phone', 'email' => 'Email', 'message' => 'Message'); 

    $okMessage = 'Contact form successfully submitted. Thank you, I will get back to you soon!';

    $errorMessage = 'There was an error while submitting the form. Please try again later';

    error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE);

    try
    {
      if(count($_POST) == 0) throw new \Exception('Form is empty');

      $emailText = "You have a new message from your contact form\n=============================\n";

      foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {

        if (isset($fields[$key])) {
            $emailText .= "$fields[$key]: $value\n";
        }
      }

      $headers = array('Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8";',
        'From: ' . $from,
        'Reply-To: ' . $from,
        'Return-Path: ' . $from,
      );

      mail($sendTo, $subject, $emailText, implode("\n", $headers));

      $responseArray = array('type' => 'success', 'message' => $okMessage);
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
      $responseArray = array('type' => 'danger', 'message' =>   $errorMessage);
    }


    // if requested by AJAX request return JSON response
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) &&      strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest') {
      $encoded = json_encode($responseArray);

      header('Content-Type: application/json');

      echo $encoded;
    }
   // else just display the message
   else {
    echo $responseArray['message'];
   }
```

contact.js:

```
  $(function () {

  // downloaded validator files from http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator

    $('#contact-form').validator();

    // when the form is submitted
    $('#contact-form').on('submit', function (e) {

        // if the validator does not prevent form submit
        if (!e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
            var url = "contact.php";

            // POST values in the background the the script URL
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: url,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (data)
                {
                    // data = JSON object that contact.php returns

                    // we receive the type of the message: success x danger and apply it to the 
                    var messageAlert = 'alert-' + data.type;
                    var messageText = data.message;

                    // let's compose Bootstrap alert box HTML
                    var alertBox = '<div class="alert ' + messageAlert + ' alert-dismissable"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' + messageText + '</div>';

                    // If we have messageAlert and messageText
                    if (messageAlert && messageText) {
                        // inject the alert to .messages div in our form
                        $('#contact-form').find('.messages').html(alertBox);
                        // empty the form
                        $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                    }
                }
             });
            return false;
          }
       })
  });
```

Comment: your /php/contact.php  ...file is not found ,  put contact.php outside php folder and try  action="contact.php"

Comment: So you're running two servers for your site? How are you preventing express from trying to serve `/php/contact.php`?

Comment: @hungerstar Yeah, I'm a noob and was trying Express out but don't need it. I'll remove Express and try it again but I'm not sure how to redo my index.js. Will have to research.

Comment: @saurabh-mistry I tried putting the contact.php outside of the folder and with the contact.ejs and that didn't work. I suspect HUNGERSTAR is correct about my problem.

Comment: If you're a beginner I would stick to a single server and backend server-side language. Is there a specific reason the post for the form has to be in PHP and not Express?

Comment: @hungerstar No. I already had Express but was following the tutorial that used PHP and didn't realize. I'm not sure how to POST like the PHP script does with Express.

Comment: @Kathy Google `express submit form`.

Comment: @hungerstar I tried Google with "express submit form" but wasn't able to figure out how to do what is in this PHP script with Express. It's all going over my head. Thanks, though.

Comment: @Kathy it's there. Take your time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not deep enough on node and express to fully know if your JavaScript is solid or not. Only advice I could give is to try the JS shown on that tutorial, and put the files in the same spot together. Basically recreate it all.

After that, try putting contact.php in the php folder and fix the action. See if that works.

If so, then you'll know it's your JS. I know Bootstrap is reliant on JQuery, so you might want to consider using their script if you are already using JQuery for other functions of Bootstrap. If not, then just go step by step with plenty of error messaging until you find where you hit an issue.

Sorry I can't be of better help. Good luck!

Comment: Welcome to SO! Generally if you don't have a good answer, it's best to leave a comment on the question instead.

Comment: Got it. Sorry about that.

Comment: @InternetArtisan I have script tags linking to:                                             <script src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js'></script>
<script src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

Comment: Right, but what I was saying is it looks like you're trying to rewrite the JS the tutorial gave using node and express.  My question is "why?"

If Bootstrap already needs JQuery to run, then why not use the JQuery script given in the tutorial?  Is your Express script more optimized or is it just a personal preference?

I'm of the mind to not use too many frameworks in a site build, so if a client requests I use Bootstrap, then I'll try to stick to JQuery for other JavaScripts, usually putting in the noConflict function to keep scripts from  hindering one another.

Comment: @JacobWood, I also just found I couldn't comment because I didn't have 50 rep.  I'll eventually get there, but it explains why I didn't see the option.

Comment: @InternetArtisan Express and jQuery are two different things. One is a web server and the other is not. Thre is nothing wrong with using Express to serve your site and jQuery to do the DOM stuff. Please don't confuse Kathy.

Comment: Sorry if I'm coming off as a troublemaker, but I was curious why the Expressjs.  I've read what it does, but from my experiences with forms like this, the JS is mainly to transport the data to the PHP without refreshing the page.  The PHP is to take the data and send it out as an email.  You're on top of this, so I'll ask you...can Expressjs replace the DOM functions the jQuery JS file would have done? At this point I only assumed Expressjs would be more ideal to replace the PHP portion of this equation.  Again, I'm not trying to cause trouble, but to understand as well.